# Add "email" to /admin/people overlay view

Tags: views, 7, users

I have been browsing around trying to find the answer to this but I am not having any luck. I want to add the users email to the table so that we can identify them easier. I have tried to create a new page and use "/admin/people" as the path but I get the error that it can not be overridden. I am relatively new to Drupal so if it sounds like a noob question that is why.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Drupal Answers. It seems a bit unclear what exactly you are trying to accomplish. Which table are you referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) for this? This will work well if you want to make a new page that lists all of the users. It won't work out of the box if you want to add the email information to the existing admin/people overlay.

- To use Views, enable the module and go to admin/structure/views/add
- Give the View a name, and then for the 'Show:' option from the
  dropdown select 'Users'
- To create a new page, leave the 'create a new page' item checked, give the new page a title and path, and under Display Format select 'Fields' Hit Continue and Edit
- On the next screen under Fields hit the Add button, and select User:email

There are tons of options to configure with Views - check out the [Views Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/views) for more information if you're new to Views.

Comment: I have the view created like you said and it will take me to a page and display what I want but I would like it to display like the people as an overlay, I do not see an option for that, also the table matches the existing people table style in the view editor but on the new page itself it is different colors.

Comment: I got it figured out

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to @kbrinner answers, I recommend installing the [Admin Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_views) module.

This module:

> Replaces administrative overview/listing pages with actual views for
>   superior usability.

By doing this you can then edit the People view and add the email column for all users.